# C# code to decrypt data in SQLite field

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption, caesar-cipher

A partner was fired, and did not leave source code. We have an sqlite database where a field is encrypted. We have solved the encryption, and it is only a substitution of letters in a random way and case sensitive (Almost like Caesar cipher):

This is our cipher code:

```
Plain:   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Cipher:  I O C N E P Z B J T D U S H X Q K W A R V L F M G Y i p n s w a j e o b q f c t r x d y k z h m u g l v 4 3 9 6 1 7 8 5 0 2
```

And this is an example:

```
Plaintext:  My text
Ciphertext: Sl zwgz
```

Can you help me with some C# code to decrypt it?

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: FYI once you get all this decoded, you should switch to using a FIPS compliant encryption algorithm like AES256 on the data. If it's worth protecting, it should actually BE protected. This type of substitution cipher is trivially easy to recover the data from even without knowing the key.

Comment: @AntonGogolev Use two arrays, but I did not think the best way.

Comment: @JamieSee Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Dictionary and use the first char as key and the second as value.

```
Dictionary<char, char> dict = new Dictionary<char, char>();
dict.Add('A', 'I');
dict.Add('B', 'O');
...

char x = 'A';
return dict[x];
```

Or even better, use the position of chars in strings:

```
string plain = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
string cipher = "IOCNEPZBJTDUSHXQKWARVLFMGYipnswajeobqfctrxdykzhmuglv4396178502";

char x = 'A';
return cipher[plain.IndexOf(x)];
```

With the second posibility it simple to turn around encryption and decryption easily by swaping plain and cipher

Comment: Excelent! I'll try the second posibility :)